# How to search multiple columns with 2 or more keywords

Tags: php, mysql

So right now, there is a searchbar which searches in each column for the term you enter eg.

```
+--------+------------+
|  name  |  location  |
+--------+------------+
| Miley  | House      |
+--------+------------+
|  Bob   | Hotel      |
+--------+------------+
```

so when you search for Miley you get output the table row with Miley|House, same if you search for House you also get Miley|House. However if I input "Miley House" in the searchbar and it doesnt output anytghing.

code:

```
<input type="text" id="search"  name="search" value="" >
```

SQL

```
WHERE CONCAT(id, name, department, object, description, location, room, reg_date, until_date, reason, email) LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Would be nice if you could help me :) how to search with multiple keywords.

Comment: Look into using MySQL's full text search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(`id`, `name`, `department`, `object`, `description`, `location`, `room`, `reg_date`, `until_date`, `reason`, `email`) as all_str FROM `tbl_name` 
WHERE `all_str` LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(`id`, `name`, `department`, `object`, `description`, `location`, `room`, `reg_date`, `until_date`, `reason`, `email`) as data FROM `tablename` 
WHERE name LIKE '%fieldname%' OR location LIKE '%fieldname%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey if u want to better result for searching the data in MySql database then u can use the concept of full-text search in which u have to change the structure of table becz full-text search based upon the fulltext index concept.

****Demo****

CREATE TABLE articles (
      id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(200),
      body TEXT,
      FULLTEXT (title,body) *//   full text index*
      );

INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
     ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
     ('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
     ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
     ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
     ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
     ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');

*Here if u want to best result then fire below query .*
SELECT title,body,MATCH (title,body)    AGAINST ('DBMS stands for DataBase' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) all_data  FROM articles order by all_data desc limit 1;

I think it's helpful for u ..........

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Well, can u tell me where my process is not valid .. in question have a two field in data base and they want to search best result based upon given data.  @Oleksandr Kaleniuk